# Can we use the idiom "now that" when referring to past events?

Tags: usage, idioms

Please consider the following scenario:

> Now that he'd got/gotten the truth, his face enlightened.

I know that [now that](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/now+that) is an idiom and should be taken as such, and since it may mean **since** I don't see any impediment in using it.

On the other hand, now, according to the [American Heritage of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/now), definition #3:

> 3. In the immediate past; very recently: left the room just now.

So, since my sentence refers to a **now** used in a distant past I wonder if there might be any conflictual semantic in it.

Note: in my language such example is perfectly valid.

Comment: I don't know that this answers your question well, but I would use "since he'd gotten the thuth" for a past tence version of "now that". This isn't a direct "translation," but in most cases it should convey the meaning well and understandebily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Now that" is a phrase used by someone who is telling a story (broadly construed, not necessarily an author; it could be anyone, in casual conversation, say) and it establishes a reference time or a reference context.

> I came in out of the storm and took off my boots and heavy coat, and
>   put on the kettle for a cup of tea. *Now that* I was indoors and out of
>   the bitter cold, a cup of tea in my hand, it gave me a cozy feeling to
>   look out the window at the snow.

In this little narrative, "now" refers to a context in the past, as far as the listener is concerned, but it was the *present* condition of the "I" in the story. You can think of it as an invitation to the listener to enter the speaker's frame of reference.  **Now** is deictic.

It can also be used to establish a reference time/reference context in conversation:

> Now that you've finished your degree, what do you plan to do?